# Why { ...arg} are used inside the components of react -daisyUi

Tags: r-daisy, daisyui

Why {...arg} are passed inside the daisyUi component.
All components have internal {...arg} . But what does it do.

```
  return <Button {...args} />
```

Another one

```
<Dropdown {...args}>
    <Dropdown.Toggle>Click</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu className="w-52">
    <Dropdown.Item>Item 1</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item>Item 2</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

```
  return <Swap {...args} />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a frustration of mine too. Their docs just aren't very good. Basically `args` is an object of props, and `{...args}` can be used to unpack that object, as though they were props to the component.

If we look at Dropdown, we could set the `hover` option like:

```js
const args = {hover: true}
<Dropdown {...args}>
...  //and so on
```

(More realistically probably from function props or something)

or like

```js
<Dropdown hover >
... //and so on
```

Which to me is a lot more readable, but isn't as flexible if this is a part of a larger component or something.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, args is a Storybook thing.

Please check—

1. https://storybook.js.org
2. https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33263564)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).